# Passing partial view with new model

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having issues passing a separate model and partial view into my index page. Below I can render the partial view but it wont hit the method "Opening" from my controller

Partial View

```
@model IList<DatabaseName.Models.Script>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    @item.ScriptName
}
```

Index

```
@model DatabaseName.Models.Lead

<div class="opening-fields">
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Scripts/_Opening.cshtml",List<DatabaseName.Models.StriptType())
</div>
```

In my Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid? id)
{
    Lead lead = db.Leads.Find(id);
    blah blah blah;
    return View(lead);
}

public ActionResult Opening()
{
     var opening = from o in db.Scripts
                   where o.ScriptTypeID == 1
                   orderby o.ScriptOrder
                   select o;
    return PartialView("~/Views/Scripts/_Opening.cshtml", opening);
}
```

Comment: `@Html.Partial()` does not call a server method (it just renders the its html based on the model you pass it). You need `@Html.Action()` to call a server method - `@Html.Action("Opening")`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below overload to call the action  method from view.

```
Public static MvcHtmlString Action(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues
)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703457.aspx

**Your Index Example :**

```
@model DatabaseName.Models.Lead

<div class="opening-fields">
@Html.Action("Opening", "ControllerName", new { routevalue1="100", routevalue2="200" });  //changed line

</div>
```

Hope it was helpful

Thanks

Karthik